# How to make sure a parameter "lang" always is present in url without adding it to all links?

Tags: php, parameters, session-variables

I have a simple multi language website. The langauge of the displayed page is controlled by the use of a session variable, but I want users to be able to copy the url and send it to other people and end up on the same language page -- that is I want the "lang" url parameter to be present in the url always.

**I could of course edit all links on the page and add it to them, but isn't there an easier way to do this? Is there an alternative solution?**

Comment: One way would be using the HTML5 History API to automagically add the parameter in the URL when the page is loaded. This has the downside though that if a user directly right-clicks a link and copies it, the parameter is not there. Another solution not suffering from this would be using different subdomains instead of parameters - assuming you don't include the domain name in your links, this should also make it work.

Comment: Dear @CherryDT, the HTML5 History API would do good for this purpose. If you have the time, it would be nice if you wrote an answer.

Comment: Your question title, doesn't match the content. Let me see if I got this straight... the user language is set on ex: `$_SESSION['lang']`, and you want to add that value to all urls, something like: `www.somesite.com/script.php?lang=pt`, `lang` doesn't need to be `en`, it can be `pt`, right?

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes :) that's correct. I changed the title so it's not confusing.

Comment: Ok, understood, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
<?php
    //get full url
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    //check if get lang exists.
    if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
        if($_GET['lang'] == "en"){
            //then do nothing.
        } else{
            //get all parameters.
            $query_arr = $_GET;
            //chang lang parameter.
            $query_arr["lang"] = "en";
            $query = http_build_query($query_arr);
            $uri_parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
            //make first part of url.
            $first_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $uri_parts[0];

            //redirect to correct url.
            header("location: " . $first_url . "?" . $query);
        }
    }else{
        //redirect to correct url.
        header("location: " . $url . "&lang=en");
    }
?>
```

Hope this is wat you meant.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how this works with some comments?

Comment: Added some comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $sessionLang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $rUri = "$protocol$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if(!(isset($_GET['lang']))){
        if (strpos($rUri, '?')) { // returns false if '?' isn't there
            $newUrl = "$rUri&$sessionLang";
            header("Location: $newUrl");
        } else {
            $newUrl = "$rUri?$sessionLang";
            header("Location: $newUrl");
        }
    }
}
```

---

1. We make sure `$_SESSION['lang']` isset.
2. Get the current url `protocol` and `uri`
3. Check if `$_GET['lang']` **isn't** already set
4. Check if the url already contains parameters (`strpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], '?')`), is so,
   append `&lang=`, otherwise append `?lang=` to it.